# JAXB - How to force adding xsi:type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm using JAXB 2.3.1.
When serializing object called GetDictionary I got:

```
<ns5:getDictionary xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns5="http://bla/bla" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <selector>
        <name>Foo.BAR</name>
    </selector>
</ns5:getDictionary>
```

I need to have `xsi:type` attribute even if it is the same name as serialized class. How to achieve that?